# Ubuntu Studio now with Pop!_OS?

Tags: updates, update-manager, ubuntu-studio

I hadn't been using my install of Ubuntu Studio 20.04 much for a few weeks, so I logged in and performed some updates. When restarting I noticed that the GRUB menu looked different and contained the name Pop!_OS in the linux options. I also can't seem to find the old Software store, but the Pop!_Shop is installed. I'm quite new to using Linux but I thought Pop!_OS and Ubuntu Studio were totally different operating systems. I am also getting notifications that updates are available for my system but the window that usually appears to download them doesn't appear. So I've just been doing it through command line but I also saw a few things that needed updating when I opened the Pop!_Shop. It's a bit confusing and hard to find any info about this online. Can anyone tell me why this has happened? and also if you can recommend the best practices for updating in future, that would be great! Thank you.

sudo apt update output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSKq4.jpg

ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7zHw.jpg

Comment: Please [edit] to add the output of `sudo apt update`.

Comment: It seems you have changed some repos...

Comment: Could you [edit] your question adding the output of the command `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: I've added screenshots of both outputs to the question :)

Comment: I don't know how I've added this though? as all I did was perform updates in the usual way.

Comment: You have added the System76 PPA which lead to this mess. See: [After update, Ubuntu has now become PopOS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308583/after-update-ubuntu-has-now-become-popos) and follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: Ubuntu and *flavors* of Ubuntu install without any PPA's included; ie. the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory is empty for all Ubuntu systems; that is mandated as no 3rd party packages are allowed to be included.  PPA = personal package archive; ie. 3rd party; so any PPAs (and look at your pastes - you'll see numerous!) were all added to your system by a user with `sudo` right/privileges.   Don't allow users to have `sudo` rights if you can't trust them.

Comment: The only thing Pop_OS related that I remember installing was the Pop_Os theme so that must have caused it.

Comment: Thank you @Someone, I followed your steps and it seems almost everything is back to normal. However, in the GRUB menu, it still says Advanced options for Pop/Linux. Is this something still left over?

Comment: You have to run `sudo update-grub`.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to remove all components of Pop!_OS:

1. Purge the repository:

   ```
   sudo apt install ppa-purge
   sudo ppa-purge system76/pop
   ```

   This will remove all conflicts/depends/packages/changes done by the PPA.
2. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
   ```
3. Reboot to confirm the changes.
4. Next, remove all packages whose name starts with `pop`. Since this can be destructive if you have any packages not related to Pop! but whose name begins with the string `pop`, first run this to just print what packages will be removed:

   ```
   sudo apt --dry-run purge pop=-* system76*
   ```

   Look over the list of packages to be purged carefully and make sure they are all related to Pop!. Once you are confident that they are, go ahead and run the command:

   ```
   sudo apt purge pop-* system76*
   ```

#### Restore the default repositories.

This step is not at all necessary but is highly recommended.

1. First, confirm if the above steps were successful.

   ```
   lsb_release -a
   ```

   If it shows Ubuntu, then you can proceed. If not, then try rebooting.
2. Run this one-line copy-paste friendly command:

   ```
   sudo mkdir ~/answer && cd ~/answer/ && sudo wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ishad0w/788555191c7037e249a439542c53e170/raw/3822ba49241e6fd851ca1c1cbcc4d7e87382f484/sources.list && sudo sed -i "s/focal/$(lsb_release -c -s)/" ~/answer/sources.list && sudo mv ~/answer/sources.list /etc/apt/ && sudo rm -rf ~/answer && sudo apt update
   ```
3. Run a full upgrade:

   ```
   sudo apt full-upgrade
   ```
4. Install Ubuntu Desktop packages:

   ```
   sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

Comment: **To our smart minded downvoter**: Consider explaining your downvote.

Comment: Agreed ^^^ +1 to compensate. Also added a comment under the accepted answer in the duplicate linking to this one because it's far batter, thorough, the the other (the other seems more focused on the installation of the Pop! software without adding the PPA).