# Ubuntu Stuck on blank screen with blinking underscore after reverting back from Pop OS

Tags: boot, grub2, amd-processor

GPG keys of tomighty were expired and hence sudo apt update was giving an error. I updated the system for a partial update from GUI. After reboot, it changed to Pop OS. I reverted back to Ubuntu using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1390854) but now my screen is stuck at a blank screen with blinking underscore on top left. I have free disk space and am able to proceed using startx on tty3 screen using ctrl+alt+F3.

I changed from quiet to nomodset in grub but it just shows some text and then moves to same blank screen. I've tried updating drivers, cleaning, and other options from recovery mode. Also ran the update and upgrade and reinstalled ubuntu-desktop but it's still not working. How can I fix this issue without having to reinstall ubuntu?

Comment: After reboot, it changed to Pop OS This can not happen you must have not stated something.

Comment: *How can I fix this issue without having to reinstall ubuntu?* You probably can't. Too much mistakes pilling on top of other mistakes and too much confusion, no clear goal, mixed kernels, etc. The time you already spent for nothing is enough to install Ubuntu from scratch 3x at least.

Comment: @ChanganAuto true. I'll just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @David It really happened. Other people have also faced same issue. Don't know the exact reason however but It definitely doing the partial update.